# Log the conversation to Azure CosmosDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework

We're trying to save the conversations for analytics purposes, and since we're using CosmosDB to store the User and Conversation States, we would like to log the conversations there too.

I've been able to find ways to do so using BlobStorage but that isn't really possible for us.

Is there any way or implementation that we can follow/use to log into CosmosDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom logger to do this. This is implemented in index.js via TranscriptLoggerMiddleware (part of botbuilderlibrary). The main additions to index.js here are:

```js
const { TranscriptLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder')
const { CustomLogger } = require('./helpers/CustomLogger');

const logger = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new CustomLogger());
adapter.use(logger);
```

For the logger itself, because of the speed of the request/response, we found that often only one part of the conversation was getting logged. So we created a for-loop delay function. I've tried other methods such as awaiting a promise, but it didn't fix the issue. This has been rock solid after adding the delay. Here is the full custom logger code:

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const { CosmosDbStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

class CustomLogger {

    // Set up Cosmos Storage
    constructor() {
        this.transcriptStorage = new CosmosDbStorage({
            serviceEndpoint: process.env.ACTUAL_SERVICE_ENDPOINT,
            authKey: process.env.ACTUAL_AUTH_KEY,
            databaseId: process.env.DATABASE,
            collectionId: 'bot-transcripts'
        });

        this.conversationLogger = {};

        this.msDelay = 250;
    }


    async logActivity(activity) {

        if (!activity) {
            throw new Error('Activity is required.');
        }

        // Log only if this is type message
        if (activity.type === 'message') {

            // Check if activity contains a card
            if (activity.attachments) {
                var logTextDb = `${activity.from.name}: ${activity.attachments[0].content.text}`;
            } else {
                var logTextDb = `${activity.from.name}: ${activity.text}`;
            }

            if (activity.conversation) {
                var id = activity.conversation.id;
                if (id.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
                    id = activity.conversation.id.replace(/\|.*/, '');
                }

                // Get today's date for datestamp
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var day = currentDate.getDate();
                var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
                var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
                var datestamp = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                var fileName = `${datestamp}_${id}`;

                var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1);

                // Prep object for CosmosDB logging
                if (!(fileName in this.conversationLogger)) {
                    this.conversationLogger[fileName] = {};
                    this.conversationLogger[fileName]['botName'] = process.env.BOTNAME;
                }

                this.conversationLogger[fileName][timestamp] = logTextDb;

                let updateObj = {

                    [fileName]:{
                        ...this.conversationLogger[fileName]
                    }

                }

                // Add delay to ensure messages logged sequentially
                await this.wait(this.msDelay);

                // Write to CosmosDB
                try {
                    let result = await this.transcriptStorage.write(updateObj);
                    console.log(`Transcript written successfully to DB\n\n`);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(`There was an error writing the transcript to DB`);
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    async wait(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
exports.CustomLogger = CustomLogger;
```

Comment: Although your example has been helpful, I'm finding some concurrency and overwrite issues with that logger when the bot gets updated or restarted, which isn't something we want to happen. I'll get back to you If I'm able to form a more complete solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: That's interesting...I haven't had any issues after adding the delay function. Are you having the issues after a service restart when updating code (or just restarting the service) or are there other things causing those restarts? You could try increasing the delay timer. I don't know why that even works, but it fixed concurrency issues for me. I reduced it to the lowest delay where things still worked for me, but maybe that number is higher for your setup.

Comment: It's quite a complex issue to reproduce, but in the case of a restart, and that a user continues a previous conversation with the new instance of the bot, the log of that conversation will be overwritten, also working with a delay doesn't work for us since response times can vary depending in location and number of requests.